# How does instance_eval work in this case? What is going on?

Tags: ruby

What does `instance_eval` do when it's passed a binding? I'm confused at this code:

```
require 'erb'
require 'ostruct'
namespace = OpenStruct.new(name: 'Joan', last: 'Maragall')
template = 'Name: <%= name %> <%= last %>'
result = ERB.new(template).result(namespace.instance_eval { binding })
```

I read from the docs that `instance_eval`:z

> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables.

So `binding` is run inside the context of the receiver which is the `OpenStruct`. But then how does the template get `name` and `last`? I feel like I'm missing a step.

Namely, I'm confused why this happens:

```
result = ERB.new(template).result(namespace)
TypeError: wrong argument type OpenStruct (expected binding)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So binding is run inside the context of the receiver which is the OpenStruct.

Correct.

> But then how does the template get `name` and `last`?

Not sure what confuses you. When `namespace` is `self`, methods `name` and `last` are available. Because they're methods on `namespace`. And then you pass that binding to ERB (because it is the return value of the `instance_eval`). That's how it gets them.

Comment: I'm confused why I need the binding.

Comment: @Jwan622 You need a binding because the `ERB#result` expects a binding as the argument. You can't pass the binding of the current context (i.e. `ERB.new(template).result(binding)`) because `name` and `last` would be unavailable. You need a binding from the `namespace`. How can you grab a binding from other object? `obj.instance_eval {binding}`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `ERB.new('Name: <%= name %> <%= last %>')` compiles the template into a string containing:

```
#coding:UTF-8
_erbout = String.new
_erbout.concat "Name: "
_erbout.concat(( name ).to_s)
_erbout.concat " "
_erbout.concat(( last ).to_s)
_erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
```

Which is roughly equivalent to a string containing:

```
"Name: #{name} #{last}"
```

I'm using the latter (because it is shorter) along with the `namespace` object from your example:

```
require 'ostruct'
namespace = OpenStruct.new(name: 'Joan', last: 'Maragall')
```

`ERB#result` now merely [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)'s this string in the context of the given binding: (note the double quoting, `eval` is performing the string interpolation)

```
eval('"Name: #{name} #{last}"', namespace.instance_eval { binding })
#=> "Name: Joan Maragall"
```

we could also move `eval` into the block:

```
namespace.instance_eval { eval('"Name: #{name} #{last}"', binding) }
#=> "Name: Joan Maragall"
```

which makes the explicit `binding` superfluous:

```
namespace.instance_eval { eval('"Name: #{name} #{last}"') }
#=> "Name: Joan Maragall"
```

which could be further reduced to:

```
namespace.instance_eval('"Name: #{name} #{last}"')
#=> "Name: Joan Maragall"
```